# Cant resolve Service Parameters

Tags: angular, service

I have a service referenced in app.module providers that is throwing the error below. The service isnt being used in my code (I removed it to do error checking). If i remove the reference in my providers my code works. What is wrong with the service?

`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: (?).`

```
import { ArgosUserModel } from '../argos.user.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getUsers(): Observable<ArgosUserModel[]> {
        return this.http.get<ArgosUserModel[]>('/api/argos/GetArgosUsers');
    }
}
```

Comment: @KarolTrybulec cant believe I forgot that. Will you propose it as an answer?